# Warning is coming in objective-c language

Tags: iphone

NSDate may not resond to DscriptionWithCalenderFormatZone:locale

Comment: Please provide: (a) the code that causes the error you are seeing, and (b) the actual, complete error message.

Comment: There is no `DscriptionWithCalenderFormatZone:locale` method, it's `descriptionWithCalendarFormat:X timeZone:Y locale:Z` where X Y Z are a NSString NSTimeZone and id respectively. Notice the change in parameters, capitalization, and spelling. Really spelling? You should have seen that.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers are spelling sensitive, the correct message to send is:

[`- (NSString *)descriptionWithCalendarFormat:(NSString *)formatString timeZone:(NSTimeZone *)aTimeZone locale:(id)localeDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:)